# Scope ignored by FB oauth2 login flow

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I seem to be having troubles setting the correct permissions at login for facebook. It looks like my scope list is completely ignored (not in user permissions, not even asked for in the dialog window). What am I doing wrong here?

The auth url I am using is: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=CLIENTID&redirect_uri=REDIRECTURI&response_type=code&scope=email,user_birthday,user_education_history,user_interests,user_relationships,user_relationship_details,user_work_history,user_likes,user_location,user_photos,read_stream,offline_access,publish_stream&state=STATE

CLIENTID, REDIRECTURI and STATE are placeholders obviously...

Comment: You need to stop working with way old code that you simply copied from somewhere, and start reading the documentation instead … f.e. `offline_access` and `publish_stream` don’t even _exist_ any more. And you need to be aware that you need any permissions besides the three basic ones (for profile, friends and email) _reviewed_ by Facebook now, before you can ask users that are not an admin/developer/tester of the app for them.

Comment: The code wasn't copied, just old. Just found out what you so kindly explained. Thanks for the time.